# Handle date with mask and uib-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm looking for a way to use uib-datepicker and some kind of mask for the user input but the uib-mask is not suitable for work with js Date() types.

In the default uib-datepicker samples the users must enter a correct and complete date like "02/26/2016", including the '/' chars but I would like to allow users to enter just the numbers when typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it the Angular way, i would use something like this

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
  placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" min="2001-01-01T00:00:00" max="2013-12-31T00:00:00" required />
```

Se more here: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D